# Experiencing unusable display issue with Android Studio on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, ubuntu, editor

### Background

I'm trying to use [Android Studio 3.3 Canary 8](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/) (the latest Preview release). I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64-bit, and if it's relevant, my desktop environment is KDE Plasma and my window manager is KWin.

### Issue

It was working completely fine until a couple of days ago, when I began experiencing an unusual display bug which rendered the editor completely unusable for me.

Here are a couple of screenshots of what Studio looks like right now. The first one is the Tip of the Day window that pops up at startup, and the second one is the actual editor itself.

[image: Tip of the Day]
[image: Android Studio]

From what I can tell, it seems that all UI elements have been stretched vertically, or something along those lines.

### Troubleshooting

I tried Googling around for my issue, but I'm not entirely sure what to even Google in the first place. I tried some variations of "Android Studio display bug" or "Android Studio UI vertically stretched", things along those lines, but most search results apply to Android applications and not the editor itself.

I suspect that there's an issue with Android Studio's DPI detection, but I have no way of fixing any issues there given the fact that I can't see any text anywhere.

### Attempted Fixes

- I tried redownloading Android Studio from their website and running that fresh install. No dice.
- I tried completely removing any Android Studio configuration or cache folders and reinstalling. Nope.
- I tried using the release candidate instead of the Canary build. That didn't work so I tried using the stable release (3.1.4), which didn't work either.
- I tried rebooting my computer too, but the issue persists.

I can't think of anything on my computer that might have changed between the last time Android Studio worked fine and now. I do remember installing some system updates, but I'm not sure which ones specifically (if there's a way to find out what updates were installed for a given run of `sudo apt upgrade`, I can include that information in this post).

### Bottom Line

I'm really at a loss, and this is a really frustrating issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if this is the wrong place to ask I apologize. If there's any more information you might need to troubleshoot this, please let me know and I'll update this question.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Use a stable version instead

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too. Didn't help, unfortunately.